# Add tap gesture to a nested stackview

Tags: ios, swift

I've been trying to add tap gesture to a list of stackviews which are deeply nested in another stackview and a scrollview.

I'm not sure why is my implementation is not working.

In my code I'm using a selector but I would like to use a closure so I could pass into a function with parameters something like this (linkToOpen:String)->Void

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class TestViewController: UIViewController {

    var aboutText:[String] = []
    var fbLinks:[String] = []

    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    let stackView = UIStackView()

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTapCard(sender: )))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Add and setup scroll view
        self.view.addSubview(self.scrollView)
        self.scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;


        //Constrain scroll view
        self.scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true;
        self.scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true;
        self.scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true;
        self.scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true;

        self.scrollView.addSubview(self.stackView)
        self.stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.stackView.axis = .vertical
        self.stackView.alignment = UIStackView.Alignment.fill
        self.stackView.spacing = 10;

        //constrain stack view to scroll view
        self.stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true;
        self.stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true;
        self.stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true;
        self.stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true;

        self.stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true;

        fbLinks.append("Some text")
        fbLinks.append("Some other text but longer")
        fbLinks.append("Some other text but way longer then the previous was")
        fbLinks.append("text again what a surprise")
        fbLinks.append("guess what this is a text too")


        for link in fbLinks
        {
            let sw:UIStackView = generateStackedItem(imageName:"bolt",text: link)
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(sw)
        }



    }

    func generateText(text:String)->UILabel
    {
        let textLabel = UILabel()

        textLabel.text  = NSLocalizedString(text, comment: "")
        textLabel.textAlignment = .left
        textLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        textLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping


        return textLabel
    }

    func generateStackedItem(imageName:String,text:String)->UIStackView
    {
        let stackView   = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis  = NSLayoutConstraint.Axis.horizontal
        stackView.distribution  = .fill
        stackView.alignment = .center
        stackView.spacing   = 5.0

        let label = generateText(text: text)

        //stackView.addArrangedSubview(imageView)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(label)

        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.heightAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true

        stackView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        stackView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

        return stackView
    }

    func openLink(link:String){
        if let url = URL(string: link) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url)
        }
    }

    @objc func didTapCard (sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
          // let clickedView = cardView[sender.view!.tag]
           print("View tapped !")
      }

}


let vc = TestViewController()
vc.view.backgroundColor = .white
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = vc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a gesture recognizer to only one view.

Think of it like a label...

If you instantiate a label, then try to add it to 4 different stack views, it will only exist in the last stack view to which you've added it.

So, you need to create a new recognizer for each view:

```
    stackView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    // create new Tap Gesture Reconizer here
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTapCard(sender:)))

    stackView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

Then, in your action selector, you can get a reference to that view (and its properties / subviews / etc):

```
@objc func didTapCard (sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if let sv = sender.view as? UIStackView,
        let label = sv.arrangedSubviews.first as? UILabel,
        let str = label.text {
            print("Stack view with:", str, "was tapped!")
        }
}
```

Here is your complete class, edited with those changes:

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController {

    var aboutText:[String] = []
    var fbLinks:[String] = []

    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    let stackView = UIStackView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Add and setup scroll view
        self.view.addSubview(self.scrollView)
        self.scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;


        //Constrain scroll view
        self.scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true;
        self.scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true;
        self.scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true;
        self.scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true;

        self.scrollView.addSubview(self.stackView)
        self.stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.stackView.axis = .vertical
        self.stackView.alignment = UIStackView.Alignment.fill
        self.stackView.spacing = 10;

        //constrain stack view to scroll view
        self.stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true;
        self.stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true;
        self.stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true;
        self.stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true;

        self.stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true;

        fbLinks.append("Some text")
        fbLinks.append("Some other text but longer")
        fbLinks.append("Some other text but way longer then the previous was")
        fbLinks.append("text again what a surprise")
        fbLinks.append("guess what this is a text too")


        for link in fbLinks
        {
            let sw:UIStackView = generateStackedItem(imageName:"bolt",text: link)
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(sw)
        }

    }

    func generateText(text:String)->UILabel
    {
        let textLabel = UILabel()

        textLabel.text  = NSLocalizedString(text, comment: "")
        textLabel.textAlignment = .left
        textLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        textLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping


        return textLabel
    }

    func generateStackedItem(imageName:String,text:String)->UIStackView
    {
        let stackView   = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis  = NSLayoutConstraint.Axis.horizontal
        stackView.distribution  = .fill
        stackView.alignment = .center
        stackView.spacing   = 5.0

        let label = generateText(text: text)

        //stackView.addArrangedSubview(imageView)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(label)

        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.heightAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true

        stackView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        // create new Tap Gesture Reconizer here
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTapCard(sender:)))

        stackView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

        return stackView
    }

    func openLink(link:String){
        if let url = URL(string: link) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url)
        }
    }

    @objc func didTapCard (sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if let sv = sender.view as? UIStackView,
            let label = sv.arrangedSubviews.first as? UILabel,
            let str = label.text {
                print("Stack view with:", str, "was tapped!")
            }
    }

}
```

Note: That *will* work, but is not a particularly great way to do it.

A better approach would probably be to create a custom class that has its own stack view with imageView and label... and its own tap gesture recognizer. Then use either closures or protocol / delegate pattern to process the action.

Comment: I thought I could reuse one UITapGestureRecognizer like it would be a function call.